# defaultValue not working when calling react-select from another component

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I'm sending a list of options from the parent `App.js` to the child component `Dropdown.js`, where I rendered them in the `Select`. Then, I wanted to set the defaultValue in `Select` so that one of the options that I defined will be selected when opening the parent page.

I've set it like `defaultValue={{ value: "strawberry", label: "Strawberry" }}`, it works if I'm doing everything in the `Dropdown.js` as the parent, but if I'm calling `Dropdown.js` as a child component, suddenly the `defaultValue` won't work anymore and it will stay blank.

Here's my codesandbox that I've developed for reference:

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-glade-sf44y?file=/src/components/Dropdown/Dropdown.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are setting `value` so it will override `defaultValue`.

Just declare `selectedOption` with default value you want:

```
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState({
    value: "strawberry",
    label: "Strawberry"
  });
```

or:

```
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState(options[1]);
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-panini-wgds2?file=/src/components/Dropdown/Dropdown.js:244-309

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed. Now I know how to declare useState like this.